# Is there a way to decode a Quoted-Printable encoding using ApplescriptObjc?

Tags: applescript, applescript-objc

I am looking for a way to decode HTML Source code from a Mail message that is encoded in Quoted-Printable encoding, and wondering if that is something that can be done in AppleScriptObjC?

I know there is a built in module in Python 3 called quopri that will do the job. So I have a fall back solution. Just hoping I can do this without the need to install Python 3 on the users machine. Since the script is built in AppleScript already, I thought that AppleScriptObjC would be the best place to go looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quoted-printable encoding standard is defined as part of [`RFC 2045`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-6.7).

To summarise briefly and in a very general sense: non-printable ASCII characters are encoded as a three-character sequence beginning with `"="` followed immediately by a two-digit hexadecimal number, which evaluates to an ASCII character code;  `"="` is, itself, encoded in the same way; lines can be up to, but not greater than, 76 characters long, for which `"="` acts as a continuation (or soft-break) character if it appears at the end of a line.

I took a superset of these rules to ensure the sufficient conditions would be met, around which the following script was written, and is presented "as is" with out any special attempts at optimisation (for which there remains scope to have done):

```
#!/usr/bin/env osascript
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
prop NSString: ref current application's NSString

prop rgex: 1024
prop utf8: 4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
on qp_decode(input)
        local input

        try # test for existence as a file path
                input as «class fsrf»
                NSString's stringWithContentsOfURL:result ¬
                        encoding:utf8 |error|:(missing value)
        on error
                input
        end try
        
        set qp to __s(result)

        replace(qp, "(?m)\\h*$", "")      # Removing trailing whitespace
        replace(qp, "(?sm)=(\\R|$)", "")  # Join lines split with a soft-break
        map(qp, "(?i)=[A-F0-9]{2}", char) # Decode escape sequences, i.e. "=HH"
end qp_decode
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# "PRIVATE" HANDLERS:
on __s(init)
        ref item 1 of {init}
end __s

to _nsstring_ from _ref given mutability:m as boolean : false
        local _ref, m, t
 
        set t to NSString's stringWithString:_ref
        if m then set t to t's mutableCopy()
        try
                set _ref's contents to t
        end try
        t
end _nsstring_

to replace(_ref, a, b)
        local _ref, a, f, t
 
        set t to _nsstring_ from _ref with mutability

        t's replaceOccurrencesOfString:a withString:b ¬
                options:rgex |range|:{0, t's |length|()}
        try
                set _ref's contents to t as text
        end try
        t as text
end replace

to map(_ref, a, func as handler)
        local _ref, a, t, f

        script
                prop fn: func
                prop t : _nsstring_ from _ref
                prop s : t's mutableCopy()
                prop index: 0

                on next()
                        t's rangeOfString:a options:rgex
                        set [j, n] to the result's [location, |length|]
                        if n = 0 then return the yield()
                        set u to (t's substringWithRange:[j, n]) as text
                        set c to fn(text 2 thru -1 of u)
                        tell s to replaceOccurrencesOfString:u ¬
                                withString:c options:0 |range|:[my index, ¬
                                |length|() - my index]
                        set index to index + j
                        set t to the substringFromIndex_(index) of s
                        
                        next()
                end next

                on yield()
                        try
                                set _ref's contents to s as text
                        end try
                        s as text
                end yield
        end script
        
        result's next()
end map

to base_10 from base_16
        # There's probably a more ASObjC-y way to do this
        local base_16

        set p to 1
        set |ξ| to 0

        script hexadecimal
                prop digits: "123456789ABCDEF"
                prop coefficients: reverse of base_16's characters
        end script

        repeat with x in hexadecimal's coefficients
                set |ξ| to |ξ| + (offset of x in (hexadecimal's digits)) * p
                set p to p * 16
        end repeat

        |ξ|
end denary

to char(k)
        if k's class = text then set k to (base_10 from k)
        character id k
end char
---------------------------------------------------------------------------❮END❯
```

The main handler you'll be calling is **`qp_decode()`**, which takes a single argument that can be a literal string or a file path at which the contents of the file is read and processed as a UTF-8 encoded string, then processed as would be a literal string argument.

I note from the comment thread that you use *Script Debugger*.  If the script fails to compile or execute, I'd recommended running the script in *Script Editor* (however, you'll need to copy/paste again from the original source here, as *Script Debugger* manipulates the contents of the clipboard prior to pasting).  I actually used `vim` and `osascript` in authoring and debugging this script, so it's virgin text.

Comment: That is amazing. Thank you so much CJK!

Answer (score 0):

Scavenging from the web, this ought to do the trick:

```
use framework "Foundation"

property NSString : class "NSString"

set coded_s to "" -- some quoted-printable string
--convert from applescript text to NSString
set coded_s to NSString's stringWithString:coded_s
-- delete line wraps
set decoded_s to coded_s's stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:("=" & return & linefeed) withString:""
-- replace = with percent
set decoded_s to decoded_s's stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:"=" withString:"%"
-- decode as percent-escaped string
set decoded_s to decoded_s's stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(current application's NSUTF8StringEncoding)
-- convert from NSString to applescript text
decoded_s as text
```

Comment: Thanks @Ted Wrigley. I must be doing something wrong because I can't get the code to work, it just comes back as "decoded_s" is missing value! See my code below!

Comment: `use framework "Foundation"
property NSString : class "NSString"

tell application "Mail"
 set theMail to the selection -- single email selected with the quoted-printable encoding
 set theSource to source of item 1 of theMail -- raw source from the QP encoded email
end tell


set coded_s to theSource -- some quoted-printable string`

Comment: FWIW, running the complete code through SD, the script seems to fail on this line:
`set decoded_s to decoded_s's stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(current application's NSUTF8StringEncoding)`
It is after that line that the script comes back with missing value.

Comment: Doing some additional research, it looks like stringByRemovingPercentEncoding has been depreciated as of 10.11. It looks like they want you to use stringByRemovingPercentEncoding instead, but that does not seem to be a drop in replacement. Trying to figure out the correct syntax now!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an example of an email with QP formatting to work with (that I'm aware of)I know that the decoding part works (as best I can test it), and the fact that it's deprecated means little (Apple deprecates a lot of methods that hang around for years). Do you know how to use the log functions in Script Editor?

Comment: Hi @Ted Wrigley. I am using Script Debugger, so I guess the answer is no, I don't know how to use the logging function of script editor. I could provide a link to a raw .eml file that is in Quoted-Printable format. And BTW, thanks for the help!

Comment: A link would work; give me something to play with, at least.  And Script Debugger also has a longing feature (though I don't use SD myself). That's something you should really pick up; logging is the best and easiest way to debug a script.

Comment: Here is a link to one of the emails I am trying to decode:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/w1xc7c4djh64et4/SampleQPEncodedFile.eml?dl=0
I guess I am lazy and I just look at the variable values that SD lets me see, and it gives pretty clear error messages. I should say that neither SD or SE have thrown any errors, the script just produces a value of "Missing Value" for the variable decoded_s when it runs the second to last line of code. decoded_s has a value after changing the "=" to "%", that data just goes away on the second to last line of code.

Comment: I don't know if the example email you sent me is typical, but if seems the only character that is encoded QP is the 'tab' character ('=09'), and that mostly for the structural visual formatting of XML and HTML code. There's no content encoding at all that I can see. Is that typical?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206087/discussion-between-chris-norman-and-ted-wrigley).